# Need better assurance what environment a WAR is using

Tags: grails, war

I have several environments for my grails project in the various config groovy files.   I want to be 100% sure at deployment time that a certain environment is being used.

I can check the `grails.env` in `application.properties`. But how can I be 100% sure of the database I am talking to?  Or what `dbCreate` switch I am using.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In my Grails projects I usually echo the Grails environment and any other diagnostic info onto a page accessible only by admins. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>environment: ${grails.util.Environment.current.name}</li>
    <li>version: ${grailsApplication.metadata.'app.version'}</li>
</ul>
```

I don't have a grails environment available to me at the moment, but I believe you should be able to access the database url at grailsApplication.config.dataSource.url
That should give you confidence that you're getting the right settings.

Comment: I confirmed that you can print out the datasource url from a gsp with ${grailsApplication.config.dataSource.url}